# Eclipse CODAN static code analysis

Tags: eclipse, codan

I am using the integrated CODAN static code analysis tool in Eclipse CDT. Is there a way to store the output of this analysis as displayed in the "Problems" window in Eclipse to a file which stores its formatting and stores the columns as shown in the Eclipse Problems Window.

I did a "Select All"--> "Copy" and "Paste" to a text file but it lost all the columns and formatting and was difficult to read.

Does Eclipse have any option/setting to store this Static code analysis output to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching I find Eclipse does not have what I asked for in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

You must paste to program like OpenOffice Calc/Microsoft Excel and vola!

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer.  It would be better if you showed some actual code examples and explained in more detail.